# Selenium support in phpunit 5

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

Was Selenium support dropped between phpunit 4 & 5?

Only asking because although the docs for [4.8](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/selenium.html) & [5.0](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) seem to suggest that Selenium is no longer supported, I can't find anything online that formally states as much.

The only part that we were using was

```
use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Keys as Keys;
```

How do we access e.g. `Keys::TAB` in phpunit5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPUnit 5 release announcement states that "The configuration file settings related to PHPUnit_Selenium [have been removed]"

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-5.0.0#removal-of-deprecated-functionality

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realised that [PHPUnit_Selenium](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium) was actually an extension, looks like I can just use https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Keys.php